# Why my filtering does not work in Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I print a set of columns from my dataset, the filtering is not working.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='course_id')

data.head()
```

![data.head()][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hczN5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHoze.png)

When I filter, it's set all the prices equals to 0

```
df = data[data['price'] == 0][['course_title', 'price']]
print(df)
```

![with filter][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PRzI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCQAR.png)

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried searching the web, but I'm couldn't find a answer

Comment: You select the rows for which the price is zero... you get zero for all the filtered prices... What else did you expect?

Comment: To be honest I don't see what is not working in your example. As pointed above you get what you are asking for with applied filter. If you want to apply another condition remeber that you need to add paranthesis like: `data[(data['price'] == 0) & (data['course_title'].str.startstwith('Introduction')]`

Comment: There are only 46 rows with price = 0. But it was showing all the rows (280) setting the price = 0. Thats's the problem. I resolved whit data.query(), but I still want to know whats was wrong with my code above.